# Merging/ joining two struct

Tags: c++, struct

I have a question here and I need your help. Let say I have two structures like below :

```
struct HE_edge
{
   double k;
}

struct HE_vert
{
 double x,y,z;
 HE_edge *e;
}
 HE_vert *head=0;
 int main()
 {

HE_vert *vert;
vert = new HE_vert;

HE_edge *ei;
ei = new HE_edge;

vert->x = 0.5;
vert->y = 1.5;
vert->z = 5.6;
vert->e->k = 10.3;
 }
```

The problem here is, I want to connect the HE_vert to HE_edge. But when I run the program the error " Unhandled exception at 0x008c1cd6 in halfedge.exe ...". Could someone explain to me, why is this happen and how to settle this problem? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your structs need semicolons at their end.

Comment: What is `HE_vert *head` for? You never use it.

Comment: Blacktempel : thanks for notify me the mistake. :)

Comment: Luiscubal : Actually before I add the struct HE_edge, I try to play around with HE_vert. I used the HE_vert to store the information from .txt file. That's why HE_vert *head is there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't initialize the `vert->e` field.

Add `vert->e = ei` before you use it.

Comment: Oh okeh.. Thanks :) .. I will try to modify my structure.. 

Thanks everyoneee!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting exception because you have not allocated memory for `vert->e`.
use `vert->e=new HE_edge` before assigning value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't set `vert->e` you get undefined behavior when you assign to `vert->e->k`. Did you mean to initialize the value as

```
vert->e = e2;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your structs need semicolons at their end.
2. You have not allocated any memory for `vert->e`.
3. Please add `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` to your main function.

Comment: His main function returns 0. Absence of the return statement in main means that the function returns 0.

Comment: Even though it does, I would still write it in the code. Edited answer.